# OG tags not working properly

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, linkedin-api

I am trying to post a link to our website www.beehivebi.com in facebook and defined the relevant OG metadata in the header file on the site. 
However, when posting a link to my website to facebook, the OG tags do not apply (content, image etc...) and no thumbnail is shown.
When posting to Google+  - it does show content and image, but not what i have defined in the OG metadata

our website is www.beehivebi.com - what am i missing?

I tried user the debugger here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.beehivebi.com and still could not figure out what the issue is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I post link to your site I get

[image]

which is exactly what debugger shows

[image]

which is relevant to markup on your site. Am I missing smth?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that it may take a little bit of time for Google+ and Facebook to recognise the tags. It took about half an hour after I put the modified pages with the og:meta tags onto the web server for google+ to see them.